# ios audio queue - how to meter audio level in buffer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, buffer, audioqueueservices, metering

I'm working on an app that should do some audio signal processing. I need to measure the audio level in each one of the buffers I get (through the Callback function). I've been searching the web for some time, and I found that there is a build-in property called Current level metering:

```
AudioQueueGetProperty(recordState->queue,kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter,meters,&dlen);
```

This property gets me the average or peak audio level, but it's not synchronised to the current buffer. 
I figured out I need to calculate the audio level from the buffer data by myself, so I had this:

```
double calcAudioRMS (SInt16 * audioData, int numOfSamples)
{
double RMS, adPercent;
RMS = 0;

for (int i=0; i<numOfSamples; i++)
{
    adPercent=audioData[i]/32768.0f;
    RMS += adPercent*adPercent;
}
RMS = sqrt(RMS / numOfSamples);
return RMS;
}
```

This function gets the audio data (casted into Sint16) and the number of samples in the current buffer. The numbers I get are indeed between 0 and 1, but they seem to be rather random and low comparing to the numbers I got from the built-in audio level metering.

The recording audio format is:

```
format->mSampleRate = 8000.0;
format->mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM; 
format->mFramesPerPacket = 1;
format->mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
format->mBytesPerFrame = 2;
format->mBytesPerPacket = 2;
format->mBitsPerChannel = 16;
format->mReserved = 0;
format->mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger |kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
```

My question is how to get the right values from the buffer? Is there a built-in function \ property for this? Or should I calculate the audio level myself, and how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u share the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation for RMS power is correct.  I'd be inclined to say that you have a fewer number of samples than Apple does, or something similar, and that would explain the difference.  You can check by inputting a loud sine wave, and checking that Apple (and you) calculate RMS power at 1/sqrt(2).

Unless there's a good reason, I would use Apple's power calculations.  I've used them, and they seem good to me.  Additionally, generally you don't want RMS power, you want RMS power as decibels, or use the `kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeterDB` constant.  (This depends on if you're trying to build an audio meter, or truly display the audio power)

Comment: Thanks jfaller. I tried a loud pure sine wave and got Apple's CurrentLevelMeter to 1, while mine maxed at 0.70. What do we make of that?

Comment: Apple is correcting the 1/sqrt(2).  Try multiplying your results by sqrt(2) and they will agree with Apple's.